# icon in pygame does not load transparency correctly

Tags: python-3.x, image, pygame, icons, transparency

I have looked over every other question related to mine and none of them worked,
here is my code so far:

```
icon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
surface= pygame.Surface(icon.get_size(), depth=24)
key = (0,255,0)
surface.fill(key, surface.get_rect())
surface.set_colorkey(key)
surface.blit(icon, (0,0))
surface.set_alpha(128) 

pygame.display.set_icon(surface)
```

The original image is:
[image]

but when executed it still contains a black background, with a barely visable 'P'

Note: sorry for really big image not sure how to scale it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to

```
icon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
icon = pygame.transform.scale(icon, (32, 32))
surface= pygame.Surface(icon.get_size())
key = (0,255,0)
surface.fill(key)
surface.set_colorkey(key)
surface.blit(icon, (0,0))

pygame.display.set_icon(surface)
```

Note the changes:

I removed `surface.set_alpha(128)` since it will not work. Only a colorkey is supported for icons, but not per-pixel alpha.

I changed `surface.fill(key, surface.get_rect())` to `surface.fill(key)` because passing `surface.get_rect()` as argument is unnecessary.

Also, the line `icon = pygame.transform.scale(icon, (32, 32))` was added to ensure the image has the right size. Bigger sizes often do not work (depending on your OS/window manager).

Comment: Thanks I’ll try that when I get home, but what does set_colorkey do